# Extract information from RCDATA resource

Tags: winapi

I have following code

```
HINSTANCE hinst = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
HRSRC hrsrc = FindResourceW(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA), RT_RCDATA);
HGLOBAL hglob = LoadResource(hinst, hrsrc);
void* pMem = LockResource(hglob);
DWORD size = SizeofResource(0, hrsrc);
```

---

Rc file contains

```
IDR_RCDATA RCDATA { "RCDATA content\0" }
```

Qeustion: How I can get this IDR_RCDATA and put into char array?

Comment: From LockResource doc : "If the loaded resource is available, the return value is a pointer to the first byte of the resource; otherwise, it is NULL."

Comment: But how I can get it? I need convert bytes to chars?

Comment: Just cast the void* into what you want

Comment: It just output some wierd chinease symbols in MessageBox instead of my string.

Comment: @alex and so what ? assume you use *MessageBox**W*** but resource in ASCII or UTF-8

Comment: I used MessageBox so its the same as MessageBoxW. Changing to  MessageBoxA helps as well. Thank you

Comment: Just don't use RT_RCDATA when RT_STRING gets the job done.

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just cast the result from LockResource to whatever you think it contains, something like this:

```
char* pMem = (char*)LockResource(hglob);
```

if it's an ANSI string.